# Is there a way to load string resources from database instead of the wicket properties file?

Tags: java, wicket, wicket-6

I need to store the string key value pairs in the database. I want to load them with the Wicket ResourceModel, so no modifications have to be made in the gui part of the application. Is there a way to do that that avoids the overwriting of [ComponentStringResourceLoader#loadStringResource()](https://ci.apache.org/projects/wicket/apidocs/6.x/org/apache/wicket/resource/loader/IStringResourceLoader.html#loadStringResource(java.lang.Class,%20java.lang.String,%20java.util.Locale,%20java.lang.String,%20java.lang.String)) ?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You need to implement `IStringResourceLoader` that reads from the DB and to register it with `getResourceSettings().getStringResourceLoaders().add(new MyDbResourceLoader())` in `MyApplication#init()` method.